# setting input field focus using jQuery on ASP.NET page user control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, focus, ascx

How would I set focus on the TxtPassword input field from this page using jQuery?  The TxtPassword input field lives in the SaveCancelDelete user control.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="BatchDetails.aspx.vb"
    Inherits="Acu.UI.Web.AccessioningBatchDetails" MasterPageFile="~/Master" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="SaveCancelDelete" Src="/SecurityDisplay/SaveCancelDelete.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="BatchEditor" Src="BatchEditor.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="PageHTMLTop" Src="/PageHTMLTop.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="PageHTMLRight" Src="/PageHTMLRight.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="AccessioningHTMLLeft" Src="/Accessioning/AccessioningHTMLLeft.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uibox1" Namespace="Acu.UI.Web" Assembly="Acu.UI.Web" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="headcontent" ContentPlaceHolderID="head">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="bodycontent" ContentPlaceHolderID="body">
    <uc1:PageHTMLTop id="PageHTMLTop" runat="server" />
    <uibox1:UIBox ID="BxWizardTitle" runat="server" Width="100%">
        <uc1:AccessioningHTMLLeft id="AccessioningHTMLLeft" title="Accessioning Dashboard"
            runat="server" />
        <uc1:BatchEditor ID="BatchEditor" runat="server" />
        <uc1:PageHTMLRight id="PageHTMLRight" runat="server" />
    </uibox1:UIBox>
    <uc1:SaveCancelDelete id="SaveCancelDelete" runat="server" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        //jQuery('#<%=TxtPassword.ClientID %>').focus();  
        //jQuery("#ctl00_body_SaveCancelDelete_TxtPassword").focus();
    });

    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute contains(`*=`) selector.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("input[id*='TxtPassword']", $("[id*='SaveCancelDelete'")).focus();  
});
```

Comment: `TxtPassword.ClientID` will be interpreted literally by jQuery. I don't think you mean to include `.ClientID`.

Comment: @Justin - Thanks for pointing out that, I didn't intend to add it. Modified my answer.

Comment: How do I do this when there are two controls, each having an input field with the id "TxtPassword"?

Comment: Also, see my answer; the `$=` rather than `*=` theoretically eliminates objects with that id contained in its id. (I.e., `txtPassword` and `txtPassword2`)

Comment: @Mr. MacGyver, if you mean `TxtPassword` is contained within the id (i.e., txtPassword and txtPassword2) then see my answer. But you *cannot have two controls with the exact same id*.

Comment: What I mean is that BatchEditor user control has an input field with id TxtPassword and SaveCancelDelete user control has an input field with id TxtPassword as well.  So the fully qualified id is different/unique when rendered to the browser.

Comment: wait... this worked: jQuery("input[id*='TxtPassword']", $("[id*='SaveCancelDelete'")).focus(); ..... this didn't work ..... jQuery("input[id*='TxtPassword']", jQuery("[id*='SaveCancelDelete'")).focus(); ..... note: I'm using jQuery and Prototype, hence the jQuery prefix ... I wonder why the "$" isn't working in the beginning?

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer .. However, just getting some extra question traffic in the mean time so I can get this question answered.  Why does the "$" work when it's embedded within jQuery()?

Comment: @Mac - When we use `$=` as attribute selector it is passed as a string . It is not what I guess you are thinking as jQuery `$` object.

Comment: I'm referring to the "$" in this line:
jQuery("input[id*='TxtPassword']", $("[id*='SaveCancelDelete'")).focus(); ... is that the one you are referring to as well?

Comment: Yes, in this line `input[name$="TxtPassword"]`

Answer (score 4):

The `[name$=""]` selector searches for a control with a name that ends with whatever is specified in the quotes.

```
$('input[name$="TxtPassword"]').focus();
```

Comment: I like this answer.. it worked great.  However, I have two user controls.. both have that same id in them.  How would I handle that?

Comment: `$('input[name$="TxtPassword"]:first').focus();` will focus on the first one that matches the selector.

Comment: What I mean is that BatchEditor user control has an input field with id TxtPassword and SaveCancelDelete user control has an input field with id TxtPassword as well. So the fully qualified id is different/unique when rendered to the browser.

Comment: I understand. You can't focus to both of them, though. And by your script above, you want to focus on page load. It will still work even though each of them have different rendered client names.

Answer (score 1):

You need a property on the uc1:SaveCancelDelete that gives you the client id of the passwort control, because you need this. On the other hand, if the password field is a visible property of the usercontrol, you could use server-side code to call `SaveCancelDelete.PasswordInputControl.Focus();` from your codebehind.

Comment: I need to use jQuery because Google Chrome is picky with styling.. I have some specific CSS styling I'm doing during the .focus that needs to be done in jQuery otherwise my background color doesn't change.  You can see my previous posts for more details.  I gave you +1 for answering though.